# unable to download data from twitter through flume

Tags: hadoop, twitter, flume, flume-ng, flume-twitter

```
bin/flume-ng agent -n TwitterAgent  --conf ./conf/ -f conf/flume-twitter.conf -Dflume.root.logger=DEBUG,console
```

When I run the above command it generate the following errors:

```
2016-05-06 13:33:31,357 (Twitter Stream consumer-1[Establishing connection]) [INFO - twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger.info(SLF4JLogger.java:83)] 404:The URI requested is invalid or the resource requested, such as a user, does not exist. Unknown URL. See Twitter Streaming API documentation at http://dev.twitter.com/pages/streaming_api
```

This is my flume-twitter.conf file located in flume/conf folder:

```
TwitterAgent.sources= Twitter TwitterAgent.channels= MemChannel TwitterAgent.sinks=HDFS TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.type = com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.channels=MemChannel TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerKey=jtlmThaz307pCCQtlw9lvrrOq TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerSecret=oaGCt6OaUas13Ji5NTnPN6TFjdSKtsAUQdq4ZhAq0BFn9jgHPU TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessToken=921523328-xxY9nrWijDSVC77iK40eRNVmRIopvLXovpoxBnDs TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessTokenSecret=fbtuDENfBNxTooPD0EEgEo15Pg51cxNQa1CochI56gqSO TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.keywords= WT20,hadoop,election,sports, cricket,Big data,IPL2016,Panamaleaks,Pollingday TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.channel=MemChannel TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.type=hdfs TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path=hdfs://HadoopMaster:9000/user/flume/tweets TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.fileType=DataStream TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.writeformat=Text TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.batchSize=1000 TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollSize=0 TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollCount=10000 TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollInterval=600 TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.type=memory TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.capacity=10000 TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.transactionCapacity=100*
```

Comment: plz anyone help thankss in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing your *flume-sources-1.x-SNAPSHOT.jar* with the jar file downloaded from this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ae2n9hj60fjicbh/flume-sources-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar?dl=0).

As Twitter broke their old APIs few days ago. The old jar file will not work. You can Download the modified jar from the link I have given above.

P.S. I am getting results through this method.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. I downloaded the jar in the given link and added it to flume_path. But when I run the flume agent, I am getting the following error `[ERROR - org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:149)] Unhandled error`