# Unable to stream twitter data using flume

Tags: hadoop, http-status-code-404, twitter4j, flume, flume-twitter

```
bin/flume-ng agent –conf ./conf/ -f conf/flume-twitter.conf -Dflume.root.logger=DEBUG,console -n TwitterAgent
```

When I run the above command it doesn't start streaming and generate following errors

```
INFO twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl: 404:The URI requested is invalid or the resource requested, such as a user, does not exist.
16/05/07 10:36:05 INFO twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl: Waiting for 10000 milliseconds
```

plz anyone help i have post my problem twice.

Comment: anyone kindly help :/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unable to download data from twitter through flume](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37067918/unable-to-download-data-from-twitter-through-flume)

Comment: `i have post my problem twice` - please do not do that.

Comment: i am still stuck in same problem the previous ans said it was the issue of keys but not true i have generated a new pair of keys but still not working.No one is helping out so what to do in situation like that

Comment: Without more details it would be hard to help you.. As you can see from the error, resource is invalid.. Post more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am facing the same issue the problem is with the Twitter stream it is down from May 4th. You can see it from this link. https://dev.twitter.com/overview/status

Comment: Yes, actually the v1 endpoints of the streaming API have been expired from now on you have to use the new endpoints. We have made modifications in the jar file you can download the jar file from this link 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/rxi6ur3emsdjlws/flume-sources-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar?dl=0'. Add this jar file in flume lib directory.